# jqGrid tree grid version 4.5.2 having trouble getting the tree to work

Tags: c#, jquery, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I'm using jqGrid 4.5.2 and jquery 2.2.2. As it is it still displays the grid like normal but no trees. Digging in the browser debugger I found that it was setting a style of left:NaNpx;. I'm not sure why it's setting the NaN. If I manually change that to 15px, the arrow appears, but the rows aren't under it, nor does it hide the child rows when clicking the arrow.

My code:

```
<table id="TabAdminAgentsGrid" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>

var grid = jQuery("#TabAdminAgentsGrid");
grid.jqGrid({
    url: '/Admin/AgentsGrid',
    altRows: true,
    altclass: 'myAltRowClass',
    autowidth: true,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['Agency', 'Name', 'Status', 'City', 'State', 'Contact'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'AgencyCode', index: 'AgencyCode', width: 18, align: 'left', sortable: true, resizable: true, sorttype: 'text', autoFit: true, stype: 'text' },
        { name: 'AgencyName', index: 'AgencyName', width: 40, align: 'left', sortable: true, resizable: true, classes: 'defaultpointer', sorttype: 'text', autoFit: true, stype: 'text' },
        { name: 'StatusCode', index: 'StatusCode', width: 10, align: 'left', sortable: true, resizable: true, classes: 'defaultpointer', formatter: function (cellvalue, options, rowObject) { if (cellvalue === 'S') { return '<span style="background-color: #e2e0e0; width: 100%;">Suspended</span>'; } else if (cellvalue === 'I') { return '<span style="background-color: #e2e0e0; width: 100%;">Inactive</span>'; } else return 'Active'; } },
        { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 30, align: 'left', sortable: true, resizable: true, classes: 'defaultpointer' },
        { name: 'State', index: 'State', width: 8, align: 'left', resizable: true, classes: 'defaultpointer' },
        { name: 'ContactName', index: 'ContactName', width: 30, align: 'left', resizable: true, classes: 'defaultpointer' }],
    height: '400px',
    width: '800px',
    treeGrid: true,
    treeGridModel: 'adjacency',
    ExpandColumn: 'AgencyCode',
    cmTemplate: { width: 70 },
    rowNum: 15,
    rowList: [15, 20, 50],
    sortname: "AgencyCode",
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: '',
    pager: "#TabAdminAgentsGridPager",
    postData: { searchParam: $("#AdminSearch").val() },

    emptyrecords: "No quotes have been submitted",
    onSelectRow: function (ids) {
        if (ids != null) {
            var data = $("#TabAdminAgentsGrid").getRowData(ids);
            GetAgency(data.AgencyCode);
        }
    },
    loadComplete: function () { $("#TabAdminAgentsGrid").setGridWidth($('#subTabs').width() - 30, true); }

}).navGrid($('#TabAdminAgentsGridPager'), { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false });
```

My Data, I created a class for the cell and tree info and one for the cell fields. Agencies will only ever have one level below them:

```
public class JSONAgent
    {
        public string AgencyCode { get; set; }
        public JSONAgentCell cell { get; set; }
        public string level { get; set; }
        public string parent { get; set; }
        public bool isLeaf { get; set; }
        public bool expanded { get; set; }
        public bool loaded { get; set; }
    }

    public class JSONAgentCell
    {
        public string AgencyCode { get; set; }
        public string AgencyName { get; set; }
        public string StatusCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string ContactName { get; set; }
    }

List<JSONAgent> agents = new List<JSONAgent>();

        foreach(var agent in agencyRecords)
        {
            JSONAgent ag = new JSONAgent();
            ag.i = agent.AgencyCode;
            ag.cell = new JSONAgentCell();
            ag.cell.AgencyCode = agent.AgencyCode;
            ag.cell.AgencyName = agent.AgencyName;
            ag.cell.StatusCode = agent.StatusCode;
            ag.cell.City = agent.City;
            ag.cell.State = agent.State;
            ag.cell.ContactName = agent.ContactName;

            if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(agent.ParentAgencyCode) || agent.ParentAgencyCode == agent.AgencyCode)
            {
                ag.level = "0";
                ag.parent = null;
                ag.isLeaf = false;
                ag.expanded = false;
                ag.loaded = true;
            }
            else
            {
                ag.level = "1";
                ag.parent = agent.ParentAgencyCode;
                ag.isLeaf = true;
                ag.expanded = false;
                ag.loaded = true;
            }
            agents.Add(ag);
        }

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page = page,
            records = totalrecords,
            rows = agents.ToArray()
        };


        return Json(jsonData);
```

Any help that can point me in the right direction is very much appreciated. I've been banging my head against a wall on this for a couple of days. Thank you.

Edit: Here is what the json looks like that is getting passed to the grid(dummy up'd the data a little):

```
{
"total": 1,
"page": 1,
"records": 4595,
"rows": [
    {
        "AgencyCode": "077112",
        "cell": {
            "AgencyCode": "077112",
            "AgencyName": "Person McPerson",
            "StatusCode": "A",
            "City": "Stockton",
            "State": "CA",
            "ContactName": "Person McPerson"
        },
        "level": "0",
        "parent": null,
        "isLeaf": false,
        "expanded": false,
        "loaded": true
    },
    {
        "AgencyCode": "077112-1",
        "cell": {
            "AgencyCode": "077112-1",
            "AgencyName": "Anon Plus Insurance",
            "StatusCode": "A",
            "City": "Stockton",
            "State": "CA",
            "ContactName": "Person McPerson"
        },
        "level": "1",
        "parent": "077112",
        "isLeaf": true,
        "expanded": false,
        "loaded": true
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the response from the server which causes this behavior?

Comment: I don't get an error saying anything is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Will check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the problem you will need to configure your jsonReader. The cell property in your response is reserved word in jsonReader. **cell** is used when repeatitems is true, but in your case you do not need repeatitems. Since grid try to autodetect repeatitems, it find **cell** property, but cell is not array - it is object. 
You will need to explicitly set repeatitems in jsonReader to false.

There are a lot of solutions (which I tested in 4.5.2 version and they work)

1.in grid options do

```
grid.jqGrid({
    ...
    jsonReader : {
        repeatitems : false
    },
    ...
});
```

2.In response instead of property **cell** write some other word like **cells**

Some notes: In order everything to be correct you will need to set unique id either in jsonReader or as **key: true** property in colModel.
It is a good idea too to set jsonmap in colModel.

All these properties are described into the documentation.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it. This is for contract work that I do at night, so I will respond later this evening with results.

Comment: Thank you again. I was able to get it working. Quick last question: is there a way to hide the arrow icon if a parent has no child? I did a google search and nothing popped up on top.

Comment: Thanks. If the parent has no child it is a leaf - you want to remove all icons from the leaf nodes - is this the question?

Comment: One possible solution is to put a empty icon for the leaf nodes - see leaf_field in **treeReader** configuration, but I'm not sure that jQuery UI theme has such field.